# how to set Java 2 security runtime permissions (IdentityAssertionLoginModule)?

Tags: websphere

The com.ibm.wsspi.security.common.auth.module.IdentityAssertionLoginModule login module is protected by the Java 2 security runtime permissions for the following: 
com.ibm.wsspi.security.common.auth.module.IdentityAssertionLoginModule.initialize
com.ibm.wsspi.security.common.auth.module.IdentityAssertionLoginModule.login

Source:http://129.33.205.81/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_8.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.zseries.doc/info/zseries/ae/csec_identity_assert_API.html

How is it done? What's the syntax?

Answer (score 0):

These are the permissions that the calling context must have in order to use those APIs only if Java 2 security is enabled in the server.  If it is, then you'll need to grant the permission in the appropriate policy file depending on what code is using the API (was.policy, app.policy, library.policy, ra.xml, etc.), and you might need to use AccessController.doPrivileged depending on what else is on your call stack.